# Hide attributes from sphinx autodoc but show them in docstring

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docstring

I want to do two things at once:
Display the attributes of a class in its docstring, so that, for example, it will available in a Jupyter notebook when I hit Shift + Tab + Tab.

However, in the Sphinx output, the docs generated with the `.. autoclass::` directive contain the attributes section, which takes up a lot of real estate and I do not want it to be there.

So let's say I have a class as follows:

```py
class TestClass:
    """
    This is a brief summary.

    Here are a few more sentences. Probably more than two.

    Attributes
    ----------
    a1 : Any
        This is the first attribute, I do not want to see it here.
    a2 : TestClass
        Oh look a recursive class
    """

    def __init__(self, a1, a2):
        """
        Initialize self

        Parameters
        ----------
        a1 : Any
            The first attribute.
        a2 : TestClass
            The second attribute.
        """
        self._a1 = a1
        self._a2 = a2

    @property
    def a1(self):
        """
        The first attribute, I want to see it here.

        Returns
        -------
        Any
            The first attribute
        """
        return self._a1

    @property
    def a2(self):
        """
        The second attribute.

        Returns
        -------
        TestClass
            The second attribute
        """
        return self._a2
```

I also have a class documentation template, with the following content:

```
{{ objname | escape | underline }}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. autoclass:: {{ objname }}

   {% block attributes %}
   {% if attributes %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Attributes') }}

   .. autosummary::
   {% for item in attributes %}
      ~{{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block methods %}
   {% if methods %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Methods') }}

   .. autosummary::
   {% for item in methods %}
      ~{{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% if attributes %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Attribute details') }}

   {% for item in attributes %}
   .. autoattribute:: {{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}

   {% if methods %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Method details') }}

   {% for item in methods %}
   .. automethod:: {{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
```

which finally results in docs which look like this:
[image: The generated docs]

I am looking for a solution which would

1. retain the attribute list, or some information about the attributes, in the docstring, and
2. omit this information in the docs.

I am OK with trying unorthodox solutions, but I cannot find any good guides on how to use Sphinx (ironically, the Sphinx docs don't help much). However, I need high levels of automation for the docs, which is why I would like a solution which uses a template, similar to what I pasted above.